# Error when trying to use fetch to perform a post request

Tags: vue.js, go

I am developing an application which consumes a backend made in golang through api rest, what I am trying to do is a login, but I am running into a problem and that is that when I want to make the request with vue it returns a error which says Unexpected end of JSON input, but I make the request for postman and it does not generate any error.
This is my file vue:

```
<script>
  import { ref } from '@vue/reactivity';
  export default {
    setup() {
      const email = ref('');
      const password = ref('');

      const submitForm = () => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/login`, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email.value,
            password: password.value,
          }),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .catch((error) => console.error(`Error: ${error}`))
          .catch((response) => console.log(`Success: ${response}`));
      };

      return {
        email,
        password,
        submitForm,
      };
    },
  };
</script>
```

and just in case this is my backend made in golang:

```
func Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    var u model.User

    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&u); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "format incorrect of json", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    user, err := function.VerificationLogin(u.Email, u.Password)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    token, err := jwt.CreateToken(user)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "ups "+err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{
        Name:    "token",
        Value:   token,
        Expires: time.Now().Add(1 * time.Hour),
    })
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the browser console's network tab to confirm that the request sent by fetch is equivalent to the one you generate with postman, if not, then fix it to be. The error itself suggests that the request body is empty, or incomplete.

Comment: yes it was one of the first things i did but the error is still

Comment: Well then where is the error coming from? Be more precise. The only json decoding error in the example code you do not print or return suggesting that the error is coming from someplace else, from some code that you haven't shown. So which part of your code is it that results in "unexpected end of JSON input"?

Comment: that's all the code i have to login

Comment: Ok, then maybe the issue is the following `.then((res) => res.json())`, I'm certain postman does not do that, and your `Login` does not return any body, so maybe trying to retrieve the *response* json in vue is the mistake you're making, but I don't know for sure since js is generally very forgiving...

Comment: you are right trying to retrieve a json that was not sent, it generated an error, thanks for your help